# Как установить Photoshop на macbook pro

Tags: установка, photoshop, macbook

Не могу установить фотошоп на мак.
 Когда-то был установлен Photoshop CS6, после установки SSD не хочет устанавливаться, выдает ошибку **"Установка на тома, учитывающие регистр, не поддерживается. Выберите другой том для установки"**. 
Как выбрать этот *"другой том"*? 
На маке стоит **SSD** *(Том APFS • APFS (чувствительный к регистру символов))* и **HDD** *(Логический том CoreStorage • Mac OS Extended (журналируемый))*. MacOS установленная на SSD. И загрузочным диском есть SSD. 
Я так понимаю, программу нужно установить на HHD, так как он не чувствительный к регистру, проблема в том - но как это сделать?
Может кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой? Или кто-то знает как это решить, буду ооочень благодарна вашей помощи)

Answer (score 2):

Вам не повезло. Чтобы заработал фотошоп, вам необходимо поменять файловую систему на регистро-независимую.

Сделать это можно несколькими способами:

1. Отформатировать ваш SSD, перед этим скинув все полезное куда-нибудь на флешку или переносной жесткий диск. После установки MacOS можно ставить фотошоп.
2. Сделать бакап используя Time Machine, отформатировать SSD, установить MacOS, восстановить бакап из Time Machine. Плюсы в том, что поддерживаются последние версии ОС. Минусы - ооочень долго. Бывают случаются баги из-за которых можно потерять все данные с жесткого диска.
3. Сделать бакап также как и во втором случае, но используя что-то более существенное, например, [CloneZilla](https://clonezilla.org/). Минус в том, что не поддерживаются последние версии ОС, не поддерживается процессоры M1. Плюсы в том, что не надо будет ничего настраивать. Система будет работать как работала, как будто просто перезагрузил компьютер.
4. Попробовать программу [iPartition](https://coriolis-systems.com/), которая как утверждают умные люди, может конвертировать файловую систему без форматирования и без переустановок. (Опять же поддержка последних версий МакОС не осуществляется).

Наверняка еще есть множество разных платных вариантов, например, от каких-нибудь Paragon, которые дают гарантии на этот процесс.

Comment: то есть нет вариантов как можно установить фотошоп без форматирование SSD?

Comment: Ну да, он так спрограммирован под винду ему нужно чтобы, например, в коде они пишут `Aaaa` или `aaaa` или `AAAA` для обозначения одного и того же файла  с именем `aAAA`